# Animating my funky menu

Tags: jquery, animation

I've been playing around with an idea for the navigation on a site I'm building for a friend. It's all going to be on one page, with the, various navigation links simply showing/hiding content as its clicked.

What I'm looking for help with, however, is animating the navigation once a link has been clicked - I've created a mock-up below:

http://jsfiddle.net/LimeBlast/pp9Hk/

As you can see, I've got a stack of boxes, each smaller than the last. If you click on one of the links, it'll automatically jump to the outer-edge boxes, with everything that was originally above/outside it, now appearing below/inside it.

The jQuery I created to do this is as follows:

```
$('#navigation').on('click', 'li', function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.prevAll().addClass('clone');
    $('.clone').clone().removeClass('clone').appendTo('#navigation');
    $('.clone').remove();
});
```

I have no idea if this is the right way to do it, but it seems to work - all I want to achieve now is for some type of animation effect to be added to it, i.e: for the selected element to slowly make its way to the outside edge, as the the elements above it appear in the inside...

(if you know what I mean?)

Can anyone help me out with this please? I'm not very good with jQuery.

Comment: Not quite what you're asking, but TiddlyWiki is a solved problem. See http://tiddlywiki.com/#Examples or http://giffmex.tiddlyspot.com/#%5B%5BTiddlyWiki%20Showcase%5D%5D for examples of sites implemented in TiddlyWiki.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) as far as the animation is concerned? Incidentally, you don't need to do all that cloning -- just prepend the clicked element and it will be moved to the start of the list. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8KrHh/

Answer (score 1):

One problem I noticed is that each menu item could only be selected once, since your cloned version wouldn't have the jQuery click listener attached. I fixed that by delegating the event, like so:

```
$('#navigation').on('click', 'li', function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.prevAll().addClass('clone');

    $('.clone').clone().removeClass('clone').appendTo('#navigation');
    $('.clone').remove();
})
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/mchail/pp9Hk/4/

**UPDATE**

I took a crack at doing the animation. Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/mchail/pp9Hk/5/

I moved the positioning out of css and into javascript. When an element is clicked, it is moved to the beginning of the list of `li`s, and each element is repositioned according to its new order in the list. jQuery's `animate` function makes it easy to add an animation during this change in positioning (it's also more browser-compatible than using css3 transitions).

Check out the `animate` docs here if you want to play with the easing: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: This is actually pretty neat now that I'm playing with it. Cool idea for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're cloning elements, you need to use event delegation:

```
$('#navigation').on('click', 'li', function(){
```

This was in your question, but not in your original fiddle.

However, you can save yourself a lot of trouble by just prepending the selected `li` (and the items following it) to the list. Doing this will move the existing element, eliminating the need to clone anything.

```
var $self = $(this);
$self.nextAll().addBack().prependTo('#navigation');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8KrHh/